# Required fields in before-save flows

Tags: visual-workflow, required-field

I've noticed that required fields are messing with before-save flows.

- I want to add a default value to few fields.
- One of the field is the required field (I am using an app from the store and it cannot be changed).
- The flow is not working for this one field, the record cannot be changed without populating manually the value.

What can I do with it? Thanks!

[image: flow assignment]
[image: it means add the value to the field]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do here, except to make the field optional. If you look at the [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) page, you'll see that requiredness is checked in step 2, before the before-save flows and triggers execute. In other words, you can't have the field be required and not change the external service. Something has to be changed.